# Best way to add/set an ipv4 LAN address in java

Tags: java, networking

I'm interested in adding an additional ipv4 local network ip address from a java application (actually Scala). So far, the only solution I've found is [runtime exec of `netsh`](http://www.coderanch.com/t/621365/java/java/change-ip-address-system-java), but I'd prefer not to have a dependency on `netsh` and use core java libraries if possible. What's the best solution for this? Moreover, it looks like even `netsh` won't work for me since I'm on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a call to `ifconfig` (or `ipconfig`/`netsh` for windows).

Using the following command:

```
ifconfig eth0 <NEW-IP> netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

In Java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","ifconfig eth0 <NEW-IP> netmask 255.255.255.0 up"});
```

Comment: This works, with the caveat that (in my case) it must be run as `sudo` and followed by `/sbin/ifup eth0`. Also, it's worth noting that this change is not persisted, so if you want to permanently set a static ip, you need another option, such as editing `/etc/network/interfaces` on linux.