# With sudo, write multiple lines to a file using sys.process in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to set my ip address as described in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028073/best-way-to-add-set-an-ipv4-lan-address-in-java). However, the best candidate method (even though it doesn't work yet) I've found seems to be to use passwordless `sudo` with the `sys.process` package since I need `sudo` privileges to perform the necessary actions as follows:

```
    import sys.process._
    val a = "sudo rm -f /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg" !
    val b = s"""sudo sh -c 'echo -e
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address $ip
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
      > /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg'""" !
    val c = "sudo /sbin/ifup eth0" !
```

There are a few issues with this:

1. I'm receiving the following error, which shows both a syntax error and failure to successfully write the file that describes `eth0` (`*.cfg` is sourced in `/etc/network/interface`):

   `-e: 1: -e: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
   Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.`
2. I have to insert `val a = ...`, `val b = ...`, etc. to make the code parse correctly. I do want to handle errors in any of these commands appropriately though.
3. It appears that file io usually uses `#>` which requires the right-hand-side to be a file, which in this case requires `sudo` in order to write to. Is there a solution for this?

How can I do this correctly and in the nicest and most idiomatic way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", s"""
rm -f /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg
echo -n "auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address $ip
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
" > /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg
/sbin/ifup eth0
""").!
```

There is no need to invoke `sudo` multiple times, instead, invoke it once and have it run several commands in a shell. `echo` needs its parameter inside quotes, otherwise `sh` will interpret newline as the end of the `echo` command. You needed `val a = ...` because of the ambiguity with postfix operators, with `.!` you can avoid this. We also need to give `!` a `Seq[String]` instead of a `String`. With a `String`, Scala will split on whitespace to separate the command and its arguments, which doesn't do what we want in this case, e.g. `sh -c 'echo x'` would get turned into `Seq("sh", "-c", "'echo", "x'")` instead of `Seq("sh", "-c", "echo x")`.

Comment: Interesting. I get the following error when running this code though: `rm: 1: rm: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: @jonderry Turns out you need to use a `Seq`, see my new edit.